# My code returns several nulls and I can't figure out the reason why

Tags: null

My assignment is to make a method that returns a substring consisting of the value stored in the array number of  characters in a give string, so lets say that the array is { 4 , 2 , 3, 2, 0} and the string is "radon", the code should then return with { "Rado", "Ra", "Rad", "Ra", "" }. My code returns with { "Rado", "null", "null", "null", "null" }

```
public static String[] stringHeads( int[] a, String b)
{
﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿int i=0;
String[] c= new String[a.length];
if (((b.length() > 0) && (i) < a.length))
{ 
c[i] = b.substring(0,a[i]);
i=i+1;
}﻿
else if (a[i]> b. length())
{
c[i] = b;
i++;
}
else 
{
c[i] = b.substring(0,0);
i++;
}
return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that inside a while or for loop or you could call recursivity.
That code you wrote just run ONCE without iterating.
For example you could do this:

```
 for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
{
String[] c= new String[a.length];
if (((b.length() > 0) && (i) < a.length))
{ 
c[i] = b.substring(0,a[i]);
}
else if (a[i]> b. length())
{
c[i] = b;
}
else 
{
c[i] = b.substring(0,0);
}
return c;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to iterate over the input array of desired string lengths. Since you already added some counting variable, we may simply use that and add two lines of code as follows.

```
public static String[] stringHeads( int[] a, String b)
{
int i=0;
String[] c= new String[a.length];
while (i < a.length) { // loop here
if (((b.length() > 0) && (i) < a.length))
{ 
c[i] = b.substring(0,a[i]);
i=i+1;
}
else if (a[i]> b. length())
{
c[i] = b;
i++;
}
else 
{
c[i] = b.substring(0,0);
i++;
}
} // end while
return c;
}
```

After having taken a closer look into your code, I guess it's safe to say that it may be simplified, since you may drop all checks for string lengths as String.substring already does that for you.

```
public static String[] heads(int[] lens, String input) {
    String[] ret = new String[lens.length];

    for (int index = 0; index != lens.length; ++index) {
        ret[index] = (input.substring(0, lens[index]));
    }

    return ret;
}
```